# While loop with two conditions joined by an AND operator in HLA. Converting C++ to HLA

Tags: c++, assembly, compilation, translate, hla

I want to translate (or manually compile) my program from c++ into HLA. The program reads an inputted number.  Then subtracting off three and tens or only tens, determine if that value ends in a zero or a three.  Three such numbers in a row win the game! One value that does not end in those numbers lose the game.

I don't know how can I do a while loop with two conditions joined by an AND operator in HLA.

```
while ((iend != 1) && (iscore < 3))
```

---

This is the full code I wrote in C++ and I want to translate it to HLA:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int inum;
  int iend = 0;
  int iscore = 0;
  int icheckthree; //To check if it ends in 3
  int icheckzero; //To check if it ends in zero

  while ((iend != 1) && (iscore < 3)) {
    cout << "Gimme a number: ";
    cin >> inum;

    //Case 1: ends in three
    icheckthree = inum - 3;
    while (icheckthree > 0) {
      icheckthree = icheckthree - 10;
      if (icheckthree == 0) {
        cout << "It ends in three!" << endl;
        iscore++;
      }
    }

    icheckzero = inum;
    while (icheckzero > 0) {
      icheckzero = icheckzero - 10;
    }
    //Case 2: ends in zero
    if (icheckzero == 0) {
      cout << "It ends in zero!" << endl;
      iscore++;
    }
    //Case 3: Loose the game
    else {
      if (icheckzero != 0) {
        if(icheckthree != 0) {
          iend = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    
    if (iend == 1) {
      cout << "\n";
      cout << "Sorry Charlie!  You lose the game!" << endl;
    }
    else if (iscore == 3) {
      cout << "\n";
      cout << "You Win The Game!" << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "Keep going..." << endl;
      cout << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually just two separate cmp/jcc, either one can take you out of the loop.  Look at how a C compiler would do it on https://godbolt.org/.  (Of course C compilers will use normal asm, not HLA, but the instructions are the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use logical transformations.

For example, the statement:

```
if ( <c1> && <c2> ) { <do-this-when-both-true> }
```

can be translated to:

```
if ( <c1> ) {
    if ( <c2> ) {
        <do-this-when-both-true>
    }
}
```

These two constructs are equivalent, but the latter does not use the conjunction.

---

A while loop can be taken to if-goto-label as follows:

```
while ( <condition> ) {
    <loop-body>
}
```

```
Loop1:
    if ( <condition> is false ) goto EndLoop1;
    <loop-body>
    goto Loop1;
EndLoop1:
```

---

Next, separately, an if statement involving the inversion of a conjunction, &&, as follows:

```
if ( <c1> && <c2> is false ) goto label;
```

aka

```
if ( ! ( <c1> && <c2> ) ) goto label;
```

Is simplified as such:

```
if ( ! <c1> || ! <c2> ) goto label;
```

This is by Demorgan's law of logic that relates negation with conjunction and disjunction.

---

And, lastly, that above disjunction can be easily simplified (similar to the conjunction simplification from above) as follows:

```
   if ( ! <c1> ) goto label;
   if ( ! <c2> ) goto label;
```

---

If the condition of a while loop is a conjunction (&&), you can put the above transformations together to create a conditional exit disjunction sequence.

Comment: Yes I made this in the

//Case 3: Loose the game
    else {
      if (icheckzero != 0) {
        if(icheckthree != 0) {
          iend = 1;
        }
      }
    }

 But I am not sure how to make it work in the while loop

Comment: Logical transformations.  Use as many as you need.  See my edit.